# Show div one by one jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have 4 divs with same class 2 of them (first and second are display) the other are hide using $('.smt:gt(1)').hide();

```
<div class="smt"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="smt"><p>2</p></div>
<div class="smt"><p>3</p></div>
<div class="smt"><p>4</p></div>
<div id="more"><p>+</p></div>
```

How can I show the other div one by one clicking on more div?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947718/faking-a-load-more-with-jquery-no-ajax-php/6947813#6947813 ... try searching first next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('#more').click(function(){ // <-- bind click event to more
    $('.smt:hidden').eq(0).show(); // <-- show first hidden div with class .smt
    // or $('.smt:hidden').first().show();
    // or $('.smt:hidden:first').show();
    // or $('.smt:hidden:eq(0)').show();
});
```